# Can a serverless application be moved to a PaaS platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have built a serverless application (a shared drive) where users can upload videos and images to a S3 bucket through a webpage. Some processing on the uploaded media is done on upload action (transcoding for videos, thumbnail creation for images). For this, two Lambda functions are written.
The serverless application uses AWS Lambda.

I would like to know if I can move this application to a PaaS platform like Elastic Beanstalk (using something like a Docker).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but depending on the language you implement your lambdas in, you might have to provide some light shimming to wrap your lambdas in a lightweight HTTP server framework.

The biggest obstacle to moving your code out of a lambda is not the lambda interface which is very simple. However, any AWS service your lambda might call are highly likely to be supported by SDKs and APIs that can also be used from any context outside of a lambda, such as code running in a docker container.

In your case, the code for handling media upload to S3 would need to use the AWS SDK for talking with S3. That SDK works equally well inside and outside of a Lambda.

If you're writing your code in Python, then [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) is a popular package that abstracts AWS Lambda interface making it easier to move your code to a docker container running gunicorn & gunicorn, or even a different cloud provider.

You'll also have to configure and build the docker containers yourself.